# How do I hook up a ceiling fan with a black, white and ground (no blue) to a white, black ground and a red wire?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

How do I hook up my remote controlled ceiling fan with a black, white and ground(doesn’t have a blue wire) to my ceiling electrical which has a black, white, ground and red wire

Comment: What was connected to what BEFORE? Was it a two-switch fan and light? Or was it a one-switch, and there are two black wires in the box that are connected to each other and were not connected to the previous fixture?

Comment: Don’t know what was hooked up before. I have a switch for the fan and a switch for the fan light on the wall. I only have 1 black and a white neutral and ground with the new light. So I need to figure out how I should hook up the red from the ceiling

Comment: It’s in the United States

Comment: @crip659 Blue is the standard 4th color in a black/white/red/blue/ground /4 cable. It's a hot color in the US. It also seems to be default for fan lights.

Comment: Is there a light switch in the room and does it work a light *other than* a light on the fan?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have the one cable coming in, ground to ground/green, white to white, black to black, cap the red, and see which switch works. If you want the other switch instead, cap the black from the box and connect red to black.

"Cap" meaning isolate, typically by putting a wirenut on the end of the unused wire.